# Draw a dependency graph using seaborn relplot

Tags: python, plot, graph, seaborn

I need to draw a dependency graph using **seaborn relplot** for my data:

```
i = 0

for d in data['pickup_datetime']:
    i+=1
    print(d, type(d), sep='    ')
    if (i == 5):
        break
```

```
2016-06-12 00:43:35    <class 'pandas._libs.tslibs.timestamps.Timestamp'>
2016-01-19 11:35:24    <class 'pandas._libs.tslibs.timestamps.Timestamp'>
2016-04-06 19:32:31    <class 'pandas._libs.tslibs.timestamps.Timestamp'>
2016-03-26 13:30:55    <class 'pandas._libs.tslibs.timestamps.Timestamp'>
```

I mean the following:
view the first week, draw points on the plot, view the second week, draw more points on the graph and so on until the end of the last week.
As a result, I would like to get some kind of point cloud: a graph of the number of trips on the day of the week for all weeks in the data.

---

Now it first sum the total number of trips on a specific day of the week and only then draws the graph:(

```
d = data['pickup_datetime']
df = pd.DataFrame(d)
df['dayofweek'] = pd.DatetimeIndex(df['pickup_datetime']).dayofweek
df['number_per_dayofweek'] = df['dayofweek'].value_counts()
df['number_per_dayofweek'] = df['number_per_dayofweek'].dropna()

plot = sns.relplot(x="dayofweek", y="number_per_dayofweek", data=df)
```

[image: down_graph]